# Comments to a specific product appear for all products

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I am developing a demo ecommerce app, where I have created products, users and comments.
Each product page should show the comments to the specific product.
I can comment product A and I can see actually then all the comments for product A, but then, if I check the page of my product B, I see also the comments of product A. So basically, all the comments are mixed up in a long list instead of being sorted for product...
Here is my github : https://github.com/Adsidera/FreshObst
The following is the partial products/_comment.html.erb for comments

```
<div class="product-reviews">

<% @comments.each do |comment| %>

    <div class="row" style="padding-left:4%;">
        <HR>
            <p><small><%= comment.user.first_name %><em><%= " #{time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)} ago" %></em></small></p>
            <div class="rated" data-score="<%= comment.rating %>"></div>

            <p><%= comment.body %></p>

            <% if signed_in? && current_user.admin? %> 
            <p><%= link_to  product_comment_path( @product, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} do %>
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i>
                <% end %>
            </p>
            <% end %>

    </div>
<% end %>
```

This one is the **Comment** controller

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController

# So admin abilities are applied to only these.  
# So public can view product without signing in.
load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:destroy]

def index

end

def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = @product.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
            format.html { redirect_to @product, alert: 'Review was created successfully'}
            format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: @product}
        else
            format.html { redirect_to @product, alert: 'Review could not be saved'}
            format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end

end

def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    product  = @comment.product
    @comment.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to @product, alert: 'Comment deleted successfully'}
            format.json {render :show, location: @product}
        end 
end

def show
end

private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :body, :rating)
end
end
```

And this is the link to my **Products** Controller https://github.com/Adsidera/FreshObst/blob/master/app/controllers/products_controller.rb

Thanks in advance for your help!
Anna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the `show` method at products controller, it's like this:

```
  def show
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      # @comment = current_user.comment.build(comment_params)
      @comments = @product.comments.order("created_at DESC")
      @comments = Comment.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3).order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

When it should be like:

```
  def show
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      @comments = @product.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3).order("created_at DESC")
  end
```